# Arrows in CSS menu are not lined up properly, when they are floated

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xgjhk0kw/5/) kind of menu.

The CSS classes used are as follows.

```css
#main_nav {
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    z-index: 300 !important;
}

#main_nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #888;
    z-index: 300 !important;
    min-width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#main_nav ul a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main_nav ul li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item {
    background:#ddd;
}

#main_nav ul li:hover {
    background: #008000;
}

#main_nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#888;
    padding:0;
}

#main_nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav ul ul a {
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px;
}

#main_nav ul ul ul {
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

#main_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

#main_nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}

.menu li:last-of-type { border-right: none; }
.menu li > a:after {float: right; margin-left: 5px; content: '\25BA'; }
.menu > li > a:after {float: right; margin-left: 5px; content: '\25BC'; }
.menu li > a.only-child:after { margin-left: 0; content: ''; }
```

The HTML code :

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:only-child").addClass("only-child");
});
```

```html
<div id="main_nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine except `float: right` in the following CSS classes.

```css
.menu li > a:after {float: right; margin-left: 5px; content: '\25BA'; }
.menu > li > a:after {float: right; margin-left: 5px; content: '\25BC'; }
```

`float: right;` is meant to float a corresponding arrow to the right of the menu. It however, does not allow the menu text and the arrow to inline properly.

The discrepancy is clearly visible on FireFox.

[image]

The picture has been taken from FireFox (31.0). The arrows are not lined up properly with the text. The menu looks good on Google Chrome (36.0.1985.143 m) and Internet Explorer (8).

How can arrows be aligned right and lined up properly?

Comment: Have you tried adding `display:table-cell;` to these classes in css?

Comment: No difference was observed by adding `display:table-cell;` to these two classes.

Comment: And this is a firefox only issue?

Comment: Yes it is only the FireFox issue (I'm currently only using Chrome  36.0.1985.143 m, FireFox 31.0 and IE 8). Among them, it happens only on FireFox.

Comment: I added these properties to your `li > a:after` classes: 
`float: right;`
`content: "►";`
`position: absolute;`
`right: 0px;` and removed the `white-space: nowrap;` which seemed to have helped.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xgjhk0kw/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of setting `float:right` you needed to use

```
position: absolute; 
right: 0px;
```

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgjhk0kw/10/)

Comment: I already tried with `right: 0` but I always forget to consider `position` :)